# Undefined index in PHP in gender

Tags: php

I'm very as in very new to PHP.
There's this error: **Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\exer1\exer1_process.php on line 6**

By looking at it, I know it got to do something with the gender.
I tried searching and looking for the error, but I just don't get it.
Please help me.

This is the code:

Process.php

```
    <?php

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $connum = $_POST['connum'];
    $studnum = $_POST['studnum'];
    $pre = 'Mr.';


    /** is_numeric validates digits
        strlen validates char lengths
    **/

    /** ctype_digit for numbers(?)
        ctype_alpha for letters(?)
    **/

    if (empty($fname)){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>First name is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    } else {
    if (ctype_digit($fname)){
        echo '<b><font color="red">First name must be alphabet only!!</font></b><br><br>';
        $fname="";
        }
        }

    if (empty($mname)){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Middle name is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    } else {
    if (ctype_digit($mname)){
        echo '<b><font color="red">Middle name must be alphabet only!!</font></b><br><br>';
        $mname="";
        }
        }

    if (empty($lname)){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Last name is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    } else {
    if (ctype_digit($lname)){
        echo '<b><font color="red">Last name must be alphabet only!!</font></b><br><br>';
        $lname="";
        }
        }

    if (empty($age)){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Age is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    } else {
        if (!is_numeric($age)){
        echo '<b><font color="red">Age must only be numeric!!</font></b><br><br>';
        $age='<font color="red" size="1">error</font>';
        }
        }

    if (empty($gender)){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Gender is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    } else {
    if ($gender=='female') {
            if ($status=='married') {
            $pre='Mrs.';
            } else {
            $pre='Ms.';
            }
            }
            }

    if ($status=="def"){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Status is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    $status="";
    }

    if (empty($connum)){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Contact number is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    } else {
        if (!is_numeric($connum)){
        echo '<b><font color="red">Contact number must only be numeric!!</font></b><br><br>';
        $connum='<font color="red" size="1">error</font>';
        }

    if (strlen($connum)<7){
        echo '<b><font color="red">Invalid Input! Contact number must be at least 7 digits.</font></b><br><br>';
        $connum='<font color="red" size="1">error</font>';
        } 
        }

    if (empty($studnum)){
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Student number is required.</font></b><br><br>";
    } else {
        if (!is_numeric($studnum)){
        echo '<b><font color="red">Student number must only be numeric!!</font></b><br><br>';
        $studnum='<font color="red" size="1">error</font>';
        }
        }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo '<b>Firstname: </b>'.$fname.'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Middlename: </b>'.$mname.'.'.'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Lastname: </b>'.$lname.'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Your Fullname: </b>'.$pre.' '.ucfirst($fname).' '.ucfirst($mname).'.'.' '.ucfirst($lname).'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Age: </b>'.$age.'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Gender: </b>'.strtoupper($gender).'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Status: </b>'.strtoupper($status).'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Contact #: </b>'.$connum.'<br/>';
    echo '<b>Student #: </b>'.$studnum.'<br/>';
    echo 'If I am not mistaken, you started college year<b>'.' '.substr($studnum,0,4).'</b>.'.'<br>';

    }



?>
```

Comment: how do you send forms to Process.php? can you insert the html codes?

Comment: Look at the side bar. Right next to this comment and you will get your answer.

Comment: The error message simply means there's no index named `gender` in your array. Do `print_r($_POST);` at the top to check if you *really* have it and make sure the casing is correct. Also, please use Google and search this site before asking. This has been asked and answered many times before. :)

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Check your form and might add the input field (select / radio) with the name gender. 
Also check first if the form is submited or simply check if all variables are given like:

```
$fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
$mname = isset($_POST['mname']) ? $_POST['mname'] : '';
$lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
$gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';
$age = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';
$status = isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : '';
$connum = isset($_POST['connum']) ? $_POST['connum'] : '';
$studnum = isset($_POST['studnum']) ? $_POST['studnum'] : '';
$pre = 'Mr.';
```

Than move "if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {" at the very beginning of your script.

Besides: Stop using abbreviationsand start using "readable names" for your variables, sooner or later you have to read your script again and than you have to think "what the heck did i mean with "connum" or "studnum", typing these few characters more right now, will cost you 1 sec today and 20 secs in a month. Above all you will lose time, when your scripts become larger than a couple of lines.

Comment: thanks! it worked! sorry if i have to use abbreviations.. the teacher instructed us to do so. :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : 'Mr.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the HTML form you are using to accept the data, the error you are getting has noting to do with php. It simply means that the `gender` variable that you have in your html form and whose value you are trying to assign to the php `$gender` variable using in the line

```
$gende = $_POST['gender'];
```

is empty. That means  `$_POST['gender']` is empty and that happens only when you mess things up at the html part of your form. Kindly post the HTML part of your code before we can help you with your problem